# How to enable a curried function to be inherited and then partially applied

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka

I'm new to Scala and trying to learn the different features.
I'm trying to declare a curried function in a trait (that takes two different arguments), half implement it in an extending class and then allow users to call the function passing it only the second argument.

Something like this:

A trait which declares a curried function:

```
trait MetricGenerator[T] {
  def NextMetricCurrying(generateVal: =>Future[MetricValue[T]])(target: ActorRef): Unit = {
      generateVal onSuccess {case mv:MetricValue[T] => println(target.path.name + " | "+ mv.toString )}
  }
}
```

Now , I want to extend a class with this trait, then "half" implement it (by passing it the first function parameter) so that the users of this class would call it like a regular function (and not curried).

I've tried something like this:

```
 class MemoryReader extends MetricGenerator[Long]{

    NextMetricCurrying({
     val p = Promise[MetricValue[Long]]
      builder(sigar => sigar.getMem) onSuccess {
         case Success(mem) => p.success(MetricValue[Long](category, key, computerId, mem.getFree /
         1024 / 1024))
      }
        p.future
      })
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you partially apply the function with only the first argument, you get a `ActorRef => Unit`. If that's what you want to expose as a function, it needs to be assigned.

```
class Foo extends MetricGenerator[Long] {
  val preparedFun: ActorRef => Unit = NextMetricCurrying(???)
  // note the form A => B
}

val bar = new Foo
bar.preparedFun(anActorRef)
```

Note that if you want to make sure `preparedFun` is callable as soon as you have a `MetricGenerator` instance, you can refactor as follows.

```
trait MetricGenerator[T] {
  protected def NextMetricCurrying(a: => Future[MetricValue[T]])(b: ActorRef): Unit

  val preparedFun: ActorRef => Unit
}
```

To go further mixing inheritance and functions, it can also be defined as following.

```
trait  MetricGenerator[T] {
  protected def NextMetricCurrying(a: => Future[MetricValue[T]])(b: ActorRef): Unit
  def nextValue: Future[MetricValue[T]]

  final def preparedFun: ActorRef => Unit = NextMetricCurrying(nextValue)
}
```

Comment: tnx, very clear. one question - in the second refactoring the preparedFun is callable tnx to the MetricGenerator impl. in the first snippet? or is it due to some other thing i missed?

Comment: The `NextMetricCurrying` is partially applied thanks to the `nextValue` the sub-classes are required to implement (instead of "manually" partially applying in the sub-classes).